# How to expand $(D_\mu \phi)^\dagger$

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

I'm trying to expand  $(D_\mu \phi)^\dagger (D^\mu \phi)$ in a Lagrangian. Where:

$$D=\partial +ieA \tag{1}$$

$A$ is a photon field.

I'm uncertain of how to expand the first half (I wrote this question as a comment in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/516077/prove-d-mu-phi-dagger-d-mu-phi-dagger).

**Is my take on this correct? Should $A$ get a complex conjugate?**

**My take on it:**

$$(D_\mu \phi)^\dagger = \phi^\dagger D_\mu ^\dagger = \phi^\dagger(\partial_\mu +ieA^\dagger_\mu) \tag{2}$$

and hence

$$\phi^\dagger D_\mu ^\dagger = \phi^\dagger(\partial_\mu +ieA^\dagger_\mu) (\partial^\mu +ieA^\mu ) \phi\\=\phi^\dagger \partial^2\phi + \phi^\dagger \partial_\mu(ieA^\mu\phi)+ \phi^\dagger ieA^\dagger_\mu \phi - \phi^\dagger e^2 A^\dagger_\mu A^\mu \phi $$

**Can this be further expanded? Is it correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rewrite $(D_\mu \phi)^\dagger = \phi^\dagger D_\mu^\dagger$ is not valid since this $D_\mu$ acts on this occurrence of $\phi,$ not on the other one.

Also, $A$ is Hermitian (real) since the photon has no electrical charge.

Thus,
$$
(D_\mu \phi)^\dagger (D^\mu \phi)
= (\partial_\mu\phi + ieA_\mu\phi)^\dagger (\partial^\mu\phi + ieA^\mu\phi)
= (\partial_\mu\phi^\dagger - ieA_\mu\phi^\dagger) (\partial^\mu\phi + ieA^\mu\phi) \\
= \partial_\mu\phi^\dagger \, \partial^\mu\phi
+ ieA^\mu \, \partial_\mu\phi^\dagger \, \phi
- ieA_\mu \, \phi^\dagger \, \partial^\mu\phi
+ e^2 A_\mu A^\mu \, \phi^\dagger\phi
,
$$
where it also has been used that $A$ commutes with $\phi$ and $\phi^\dagger.$

Comment: Oh right, it makes sense that $D_\mu$ acts on a specific a $\phi$. So if A depicted an electron then it would have a hermitian conjugate?  
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, the electron field is represented by a complex spinor.